# .png images not rendering correctly in IE7, IE8

Tags: image, internet-explorer, png, rendering

They look great in FF, Safari, but the social media icons don't render correctly in IE.

http://www.erisdesigns.net/STAGE/ED1.3/

Is this an IE problem, or something to do with how I'm creating the .pngs?

Comment: Wow the whole page looks terrible in IE.

Comment: which IE, @Stephen?  It looks fine, aside from the .png issue, in IE8 on my screen.

Comment: here's a screenshot:  http://uploadpie.com/OJ5KD  ie7

Comment: Looks like 7.  Which brings me to my next question.  When I view the source in IE, the `<head>` code hasn't updated itself to my changes.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: Hey @Stephen, fixed it.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's because you use transparency. Although it isn't as clean as the current solution, you should maybe make everything opaque.

Comment: I've tried this applying this technique: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html and it still doesn't work.  I've posted the CSS here: http://wordpress.pastebin.com/hjHE1XVb

Comment: @blackessej: No, you didn't understand me correctly. I wanted to say that you should open every .png file with an image editing program, insert a new layer with the background color of your website as color, put it behind the old layer and save the file (merging the two layers into one).

Answer (score 1):

There's a pngfix javascript add-on you can trigger with an IE conditional statement.

[PngFix](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/pnghowto.htm)

```
<!--[if lt IE 7.]>
```

Comment: I had a similar js fix add-on that I've added back to the head.  One thing that's puzzling me - When I view the source code, in any browser, it doesn't look as if the `<head>` has been updated.  Why?