# ASP.NET doesn't display an image from database in IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

i'm trying to display an image from the database in an ASP.NET web page. I'm using a generic handler, and it works fine on firefox, chrome and IE9, but not in IE8. That's my generic handler code:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        byte[] FileContent = null;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["imagen"] != null)
        {
            FileContent = GetImageFromDatabase(context.Request.QueryString["imagen"]);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(FileContent);
        }
    }
```

And i have an image in my asp page markup:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgInicio" runat="server" Width="100%" AlternateText="Inicio" />
```

Finally i call this on the load event;

```
imgInicio.ImageUrl = String.Format(@"~/ShowImage.ashx?imagen={0}", idImage);
```

I have tried it all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would break by browser. Perhaps you have CSS rules that don't work in IE8 that cause the image to not appear?

Comment: Yes, Rubens, i wrote it bad, is image in both places

Comment: vcsjones, i don't think it is because when i enter to http://ShowImage.ashx?imagen=sampleImage. IE8 show a broken image, but i workls on firefox an chrome and IE9

Comment: Another idea: does it work with different content types?

Comment: Rubens, i dont think this can be a problem with content types, becouse i have tested only with .png files, in other browsers it works fine, and even in IE9, the problem is IE8

Comment: What tool are you generating the PNG files with?

Comment: Like Dennis said, can we see the generated html? We need to see what the web browser is seeing as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

I found the solution. I don´t know why in Internet Explorer 8 you have to specify the format of the image. I had to write code to format it using System.Drawing namespace. I added a helper class with the following methods:

```
    public static Image ImageFromBytes(byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static byte[] FormatImage(byte[] buffer, ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Image img = ImageFromBytes(buffer))
            {
                img.Save(ms, format);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

And then i call the mehod inside the handler:

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite(ImageHelper.FormatImage(FileContent, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png));
```

I think that, when we convert the bytes to a System.Drawing.Image and then use the Save method to retrieve the bytes again, the framework does something, maybe add or remove some bytes, that other browsers ignore, but they are important to Internet Explorer 8. That's what i think, but it's not certain. The thing is that **it works for me**

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities to debug this situation:

- Set a breakpoint in ProcessRequest to find out whether IE requests the images from the server
- Use the Developer Tools (F12) to find out whether the images are loaded in the page, but are not rendered
- Use the Developer Tools to change the compatibility and doctype settings (were they available in IE8?) and see whether these changes have any effect on image rendering
- Make sure the images are really stored and served as .png when the web server claims they are .png (some browser may be more susceptible to MIME types than others)
- In a browser that renders the images, download the images to your local harddisk and use an image viewer to confirm that the image format is really png
- Verify that the problem is not related to earlier IE's alpha-channel and transparency problems

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to try this. One more question, how can i find out if the images are loaded in the page, but not rendered using  Developer Tools (F12)?

Comment: you can navigate the HTML tree in DevTools and select any element contained in the tree. the selected element is then highlighted by a blue box in IE. it's just a guess it might be helpful

Comment: I already checked that, and i see that the image is there, because when i save de page as complete web page, IE downloads the image, an if i open this downloaded web page with chrome or firefox i can see the image. I think that the image is loaded but not rendered

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with images showing up broken in ie8 and not in any other browsers and it turned out that my .jpg images were accidently saved as CMYK instead of RGB. Chrome, Safari, Firefox, ie9 had no problems, it was just ie8 that showed them as broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Internet Explorer 8 image of the database not working but all other browsers do.

I used BinaryWrite. I'm falling on a page of a performance test between BinaryWrite and OutputStream.write.

OutputStream.write is more performance and whether its use .. gonna set all your problem. Its set my problems on my side.

url: http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-binarywrite

Comment: Are you asking a question? If so please post it as a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Start by running the query in SQL Server Management Studio - or some other means that definitely confirms that there is data coming back.

Check that the data is in fact in the database? Are you using an Image field in the DB?

There is nothing to suggest from the question that this is IE-related. If the above steps confirm the existence and return of the data, continue by following devio's steps.

UPDATE

Per feedback it certainly looks like an IE8 (or earlier)/PNG issue.

Comment: Thank you, i can see that the image is in the database saved as image data type. When i debug the handler i see that there i comes with the bytes array. And as far as it works on other browsers, i think it is a IE problem, but i can't figure out yet

Comment: Did you try it with a JPEG? (just to narrow down issue with content type). Also, if this is in some kind of repeating control, what boolean type have you set for the IsReusable property?

Comment: Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090204/png-images-not-rendering-correctly-in-ie7-ie8

Comment: Yes i tried with a JPEG image and nothing, it shows on Firefox and IE9, and Chrome, but not on IE8

Comment: Did you remember to change the content type when testing the JPEG, from "image/png"?